# Django render a DynamoDB JSON into a HTML table

Tags: python, html, json, django, amazon-dynamodb

I'm try to use a Django page as front-end using some AWS DynamoDB tables as back-end. 
To do so, I use boto3 library and it gets the data from the table correctly but I'm not able to parse the data into a HTML table. 
I have the following in views.py

```py
def history(request):
     itemsid = list()
     agents = list()
     dates = list()
     source = list()
     dynamodb_resource('dynamodb')
     history_table = dynamodb_resource.Table('name_of_the_table')
     all_items = history_table.scan()
     for p in all_items['Items']:
       itemsid.append((p['id'])),
       agents.append((p['agent'])),
       dates.append((p['date'])),
       source.append((p['source']))
    return render(request, 'history.html', {'itemsid':itemsid, 'agents':agents, 'dates':dates, 'source':source}
```

The issue is that I don't know how to write the html code to show a table with the rows: id, agent, date and source.

I have the following in history.html

```html
<table>
  {% for i in itemsid %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    ...
```

but I don't know how to code it (how to loop it) to show the table with the lists as source.

Any idea please about how to parse a Json with the following format into a HTML with Django and Python please?.

JSON from DynamoDB:

```
{
  'Items: [ {
    'id': '94f'
    'agent': 'aws'
    'date': '04/05
    'source'
    'case1'
  }, {
    'id': 'lk42'
      ...
```

Thank you so much. I'm new in Django and in programming in general so any help is much appreciate.

Comment: Do you have a model that represents this data?

Comment: No I haven't, as I am not mapping a database I think that I don't need a model in this case. I'm receiving the data directly from DynamoDB in json format. Do I need a model then?, Do you suggest to use an intermediate database?. Thanks!

Comment: No, I was just confirming. I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django allows you to access Dictionary elements inside the template. So you could do something like this...

View:

```py
def history(request):
     dynamodb_resource('dynamodb')
     history_table = dynamodb_resource.Table('name_of_the_table')
     all_items = history_table.scan()
     return render(request, 'history.html', { items: all_items['Items'] })
```

Your template:

```py
<table>
  {% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.agent }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.source }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```